# Is this a code/script injection attack? /script><script type=

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, url

Some tried to access this URL in my rails app

`http://domain.com/apply/share/script%3E%3Cscript%20type=`

Is this an attack?

Comment: Usually what is after the apply/share/ is a 5 character alphanumeric string

Comment: Out of curiosity - have you noticed any similar requests in the meantime?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like someone is trying to find out if your application is vulnerable to Cross-Site Scripting. It is not an actual attack with a real payload, as far as you can tell from the URL. But if your application lacks validation and/or output encoding, and the supplied string in the URL is written in the HTML-output of your website, the attacker can tell that you are vulnerable to Cross-Site Scripting from the results.

You should look at your log files to find out if this was a GET or POST request. If it was a POST request, there might be a real payload in the POST-content. Unfortunately POST-content does not get logged usually, but you might be lucky if your log-level is high.

It is also a good idea to monitor future requests coming from this IP address. If you see similar requests in the future, it is quite likely, that someone is trying to find and exploit a vulnerability.